# How to know which checkbox has been ticked per row?

Tags: html, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

*Using: Coldfusion 10, JQuery 1.9, HTML5 (more HTML4)*

The title is deceptively simple for this question. I have a table which displays permissions that users have on entities within an application. To create a new user I have a FORM which allows you to enter personal details and then a table on the same page which allows you to select permissions you wish to give to this user.

So here is how the webpage table looks (sort-of):

```
EntityName  | Write | Read | Delete   // Permissions
===================================
Note        |  □    |   □   |   □     // 1 row per entity
Appointment |  □    |   □   |   □
Sale        |  □    |   □   |   □
```

*(Imagine the square boxes are checkboxes for the sake of illustration).*

The Permissions are coming from a result called `rsPermissions` (with primary key `PermissionID`). I'm looping over my `rsPermissions` resultset and creating a new header column for each one.

The EntityNames are coming from a resultset called `rsEntities` (with primary key `EntityID`). I'm looping over my `rsEntities` resultset and creating a new row for each one.

Here's the problem: I know which checkbox has been checked and can get the `PermissionID` e.g. Write or Read or Delete. But I don't know for which `EntityID` this Permission was checked. That is, I cannot seem to get the Permissions to relate to the Entities so that this combination of `PermissionID` and `EntityID` can be passed to my database for insertion into a `EntityPermission` database table as such:

```
EntityID | PermissionID 
=======================
1        |  1
1        |  2
1        |  3
2        |  1
2        |  3
3        |  1
3        |  2
```

**UPDATE TO SHOW HTML:
http://jsfiddle.net/2jZYB/**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">EntityName</th>
      <th scope="col">Write</th>
      <th scope="col">Read</th>
      <th scope="col">Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Note</td>
      <td><input name="" type="checkbox" value=""></td>
      <td><input name="" type="checkbox" value=""></td>
      <td><input name="" type="checkbox" value=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Appointment</td>
      <td><input name="" type="checkbox" value=""></td>
      <td><input name="" type="checkbox" value=""></td>
      <td><input name="" type="checkbox" value=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sale</td>
      <td><input name="" type="checkbox" value=""></td>
      <td><input name="" type="checkbox" value=""></td>
      <td><input name="" type="checkbox" value=""></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the ColdFusion markup:

```
   <cfloop query="rsEntities">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">EntityName</th>
        <cfloop query="rsPermissions">
          <th scope="col">#Permission#</th>
        </cfloop>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <cfloop>
        <tr>
          <td>#Entity#</td>
          <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#rsPermissions.RecordCount#">
            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" value=""></td>
          </cfloop>
        </tr>
      </cfloop>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Why are the names of the checkboxes not set up so you KNOW what row it is?

Comment: @TusharGupta done and added JSFiddle

Comment: Does the form allow you to enter more than one user?

Comment: @DanBracuk This form is only to do with 1 single user after you click on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the list of Permissions is very small, another option is to name each set of checkboxes by entity ID, and use the permission ID for the checkbox `value`:

```
 <cfloop query="rsEntities">
     <!--- generate a list of all entity ids --->
     <input type="hidden" name="EntityIDList" value="#rsEntities.EntityID#">

     ...
     <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#rsPermissions.RecordCount#">
         <!--- Group each set of permissions by entity id --->
         <input name="EntityPermissions_#rsEntities.EntityID#" 
               value="#rsPermissions.permissionID[i]#"
               type="checkbox" >
    </cfloop>
    ...
</cfloop>
```

The end result would be a list of permissions for each entity id. So say you checked "Read" and "Write" for the entities "Note" and "Sale", the result would be a list of permissions for each entity, ie:

```
   FORM.EntityPermissions_1 = 1,2  <== Note (Write=1,Read=2)
   FORM.EntityPermissions_3 = 1,2  <== Sale (Write=1,Read=2)
```

When the form is submitted you could loop through the entity id's, and use a simple [CROSS JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join) to insert the selected permissions into your table via an INSERT/SELECT, minimizing the overall number of database calls. A nice side benefit of this method is built in validation of the id values. (Obviously the queries should be wrapped in a cftransaction to ensure data integrity).

```
<cfloop list="#FORM.EntityIDList#" index="EntityID">

    <!--- if any permissions were assigned for this entity ....--->
    <cfif structKeyExists(FORM, "EntityPermissions_"& EntityID)
            AND listLen(FORM["EntityPermissions_"& EntityID])>

        <!--- insert them into the db ...--->
        <cfquery ...>
            SELECT e.EntityID, p.PermissionID
            FROM   EntityTable e CROSS JOIN PermissionTable p
            WHERE  e.EntityID = <cfqueryparam value="#EntityID#" .... >
            AND    p.PermissionID IN 
                   (
                       <cfqueryparam 
                            value="#FORM['EntityPermissions_'& EntityID]#" 
                            list="true" .... >
                   ) 
        </cfquery>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Thanks Leigh. I had to make further tweaks to make it work but it pretty much followed your solution as a blueprint. Rather than putting "EntityPermissions" in in the name of the checkbox, I just put the EntityID as the name and PermissionID as the value. So I end up with a key-value like EntityID:1 PermissionID:1,2,3,4. It was just a case of looping through them and inserting into the DB. Should I post my final solution as an edit?

Comment: Well, assuming I understood your model correctly (and barring any typos) it should work "as is". As long as `<cfqueryparam list="..." ...>` is used for the permission list. If it is more than just field name changes, maybe post your final code as a separate answer, so we can see the differences?

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="permission[note][1]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="permission[note][2]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="permission[note][3]" />
```

For the three checkbox of Note?

Let me know if this is applicable to your case.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to answer if we could see the HTML, not a mockup.  That said, you should be able to give each checkbox a unique name/id that you can reference in javascript or backend code.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Write_1"  name="Write_1" />  <!-- Write chk, entity 1 -->
<input type="checkbox" id="Read_1"   name="Read_1" />   <!-- Read chk, entity 1 -->
<input type="checkbox" id="Delete_1" name="Delete_1" /> <!-- Delete chk, entity 1 -->
<input type="checkbox" id="Write_2"  name="Write_2" />  <!-- Write chk, entity 2 -->
<input type="checkbox" id="Read_2"   name="Read_2" />   <!-- Read chk, entity 2 -->
<input type="checkbox" id="Delete_2" name="Delete_2" /> <!-- Delete chk, entity 2 -->
```

Or what might be easier:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Perm_1_1"  name="Perm_1_1" /> <!-- perm 1, entity 1 -->
<input type="checkbox" id="Perm_2_1"  name="Perm_2_1" /> <!-- perm 2, entity 1 -->
etc.
```

In ColdFusion, you could loop through entities and permissions to see which ones the user has checked-

```
<cfloop list="#entityList#" index="entityID">
    <cfloop list="#permissionList#" index="permID">
        <cfif IsDefined("Form.Perm_#permID#_#entityID#")>
            <!--- User has checked this permission. --->
        <cfelse>
            <!--- User has NOT checked this permission. --->
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: If I combine the EntityID with the PermissionID into a single string, how do I then seperate them and insert into a database table? So for example, Note_Write will be 1_3 (in terms of IDs). I then need to insert 1 into EntityID and 3 into PermissionID in my DB table which I'm not sure can be done?

Comment: @volumeone In ColdFusion (that's what the tag says you're using on the back end), you can use ListGetAt(). For example:  `ListGetAt("Perm_1_3", 2, "_")` returns 1  (element 2 in a list delimited by underscores)

Comment: Thank you very much Kip. This would have been the answer but leigh posted something more closely to what I ended up using.